# How to receive WM_GETMINMAXINFO message in a BHO (C#)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

I am trying to build an IE BHO in C#. I would like to receive the WM_GETMINMAXINFO messages sent to the internet explorer window in which my BHO is running. How can this be done?

Thanks,
simil

Answer (score 0):

Try [adding a message filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Can you please explain how can a message filter be added in the context of a BHO? Isn't the message filter specific to windows forms?

Comment: Looking at the source, it looks like it won't work for you.  I'll delete this answer after you reply to this comment.

Comment: It is not working. It got compiled fine. When I ran it and resized the window, it didn't get any message. It is getting messages that are sent to my "Application" (a toolbar). I tested this by catching WM_LBUTTONDOWN message. I want to catch the messages sent to the internet explorer window. Do you have any other ideas on this?